# php find something from 3 line string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is the text:

```
<tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=dynamic-memory">Internal</a></td>
<td class="nfo">16 GB, 1 GB RAM</td>
</tr>
```

How can I find `16 GB, 1 GB RAM` from text using preg_match?

Comment: Which prior research led you to this intended solution, but without usable examples?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags I'll write up an answer in a few moments.

Comment: @Tek Read past the joke answers for once. Parsing ain't matching. And rewarding no-effort questions with meme-compliant but excessively duplicated DOM answers will not educate newbies.

Comment: I believe educating newbies includes telling them to use the proper tools for the job. If you need something from an HTML document regex is not the tool for the job here. Thanks for marking it as duplicate though.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do this like this:

```
$str = '<tr>
<td class="ttl"><a href="glossary.php3?term=dynamic-memory">Internal</a></td>
<td class="nfo">16 GB, 1 GB RAM</td>
</tr>';

preg_match('/\<td class="nfo"\>(.+?)\<\/td\>/', $str, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <td class="nfo">16 GB, 1 GB RAM</td>
    [1] => 16 GB, 1 GB RAM
)
```

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML, they should use DOMDoc.

Answer (score -1):

```
$pattern = "/<td class=\"nfo\">(.*?)<\/td>/s";
preg_match($pattern, $stringtomatch, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Result

```
16 GB, 1 GB RAM
```

Comment: I wasn't the one to down vote you. However, it's probably like I've commented in the other answer. You don't retrieve information from HTML with regex